# Matplotlib 3d plotting how to make markers smaller so object shape can be seen like a wireframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a small xyz file of a 3d object in Python. Unfortunately it's a little too thick, see below:

[image]

Code below is what generated it:

```
input_file = sys.argv[1];
print("input_file :: "+str(input_file))

data = pd.read_csv(input_file, header=None)
data = data.to_numpy();

print("----- Data read successfully. Shape and random row: ------")
print(data.shape)
print(data[123,:])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], linewidth=1)
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Data is of shape `(316369, 3)` and each row's example data looks something like: `[-0.97320002  0.44980001  0.79809999]`

Here's how I'd like it look, referencing one of my 3d programs:

[image]

Are there Matplotlib settings which would let me approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `marker` and `s` (size) parameters of `scatter`:

```
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], marker='.', s=1)
```

You likely have to go through trial and error to find a nice value for `s` (you can use decimal values). Know that it is not linear but a squared value.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @mozway's answer, setting the transparency of your markers can also help. This can be accomplished with the `alpha` parameter, or by specifying an RGBA color value explicitly with a <1 alpha (preferably with the `color` keyword argument, though `c` works as well).